# Mysql Many to Many with Mapping table return one row and concatenate the values that would cause duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, concatenation

I am using mysql and have three tables one for events one for officials and a mapping table between. 
How would I query so that the following takes place:

- One single row per event
- Concatenate the multiple values for officials into the corresponding single event row.

Tables are structures as such:

```
**Official** 
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     ali
2     ahmed
3     john
4     king
6     kyle

**Event**
-------------
id    name
-------------
1     event 1
2     event 2
3     event 3

**Mapping**
-------------
id   oid   eid
-------------
1     1     1
2     3     1
3     6     2
4     1     3
5     4     3
6     5     3
7     6     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`INNER JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), see example below:-

```
SELECT 
E.id, E.name, GROUP_CONCAT(O.name) OfficialName
FROM Mapping M 
INNER JOIN Event E
    ON M.eid = E.id
INNER JOIN Official O
    ON M.oid = O.id
GROUP BY E.id
```